# Vscode width in the left side of each line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I got ugly width in Vscode. How can i git red of it.

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6QUE.png)

[The good stander](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taqpd.png)

**Edit**

Solution is in settings `"editor.tabSize" = 2`.

Comment: ...what? Did you try setting the indent to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the indent's width with the setting `"editor.tabSize"`.

You may also have to set other indent options. Go to settings and search for 'indent' to get a list of available options.

Comment: @g6u7899oiikjuu Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. This helps to focus efforts on questions without an accepted answer. Voting up (or down) is also encouraged as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).